# How to prepend items into columns based on this item order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to loop thru an array of items and put each of them inside a couple of columns. I’ve managed to do this, but I would like order to be slightly different.

I've tried to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve and what my problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yXGA7/9/

If you click the "Prepend" link, six divs will appear in the first column box. But, the order is not what I’m looking it to be. I would like it to be read (from top left):

```
5 4 3 2
1 0
```

and not:

```
1 0 3 2
5 4
```

I’m aware of that something needs to done here:

```
colCounter = 1;
cols = 4;

$("#prepend").click(function(){
  $.each(makeDivs(), function (index, value) {
    var item = $(value);
    $("#col" + colCounter).prepend(item);
    colCounter++;
    if(colCounter > cols) {
      colCounter = 1;
    }
  });  
})
```

But not sure what to do.

Anyone owho would like to help me out with this?

**UPDATE**
Unfortunately, I need to use the Prepend function. I believe "Append" would work, but cannot use that, I’m afraid.

**UPDATE 2**
I’ve updated the jsFiddle to illustrate what I would like to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/yXGA7/9/

Comment: could we know the context why prepend is needed? it seems as a really strange contraint

Comment: I’ve updated my jsFiddle to illustrate why I would need to use prepend instead of append. The new items should appear above, not below the existing items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reverse your makeDivs array and start at colCounter at 2 to working your ways backwards:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ds = makeDivs();
    var colCount = 4; 
    var colCounter = ds.length % colCount;  // simply assign to 2 if you don't want to make it dynamic
    // push out the items to the columns

    $("#prepend").click(function(){
      $.each(ds , function (index, value) {
        var item = $(value);
        $("#col" + colCounter).prepend(item);
        colCounter--;  // go backwards
        if(colCounter < 1) {  
          colCounter = colCount; //reset to 4
        }
      });  
    })
});
function makeDivs() {
   var divs = new Array();   
   for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
      div = $('<div></div>').addClass('item');
      p = "<p>"+i+"</p>";
      div.append(p);
      divs.push(div);
    }

  return divs; // don't reverse
}
```

Be careful with global variable declarations with i, colCounter, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **prepend** use **append** like this :

```
 $("#col" + colCounter).append(item);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use the "prepend" function.

Comment: append alone just give you 2 3 4 5 @Evan Foster, why do you _need_ the preprend method?

Comment: To what end is there a "need" to use the prepend function? Append does exactly the same, but adds it after the existing content, not before. That's what you need to fix you problem.

Comment: I would like the items to be prepended instead of appended. I’ve updated the jsFiddle to illustrate what I would like to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/yXGA7/9/

Comment: We are all aware of that. Here is a new fork http://jsfiddle.net/V7MGV/ (same as my answer, but with 16 cols) but wth? If you not want a solution, and wish to upvote an incorrect answer, thats fine with me. impossible to see why you insist on prepend.

Comment: @davidkonrad the new items to should be added above the existing content, not below. But the order of the appended items are correct. Just need to lift them up above the existing items. Also, I’m a newbie on Stackoverflow and trying my best. I’m not I've voted something as the incorrect (or correct) answer. If I’ve made something bad, I’m truly sorry.

Comment: And where did you wrote that new items should be inserted above "existing content" (what that may be) in the question? Also the afterwards mysterious "i MUST use prepend" .. i give up.